# MySql Connector (python) and SQLAlchemy Unicode problem

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy

I am using the mysql connector (https://launchpad.net/myconnpy) with SQLAlchemy and, though the table is definitely UTF8, any string columns returned are just normal strings not unicode. The documentation doesn't list any specific parameters for UTF8/unicode support for the mysql connector driver so I borrowed from the mysqldb driver. Here is my connect string:

mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@myserver.com/mydbname?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0

I'd really prefer to keep using this all-python mysql driver. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To work with Unicode python objects you should set the optional parameter *convert_unicode* to True when specifying a character column type:

```
users = Table('users', metadata,
              Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
              Column('name', String(100, convert_unicode=True))
```

You could also use the *Unicode* type. Check the documentation for details: [String](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) and [Unicode](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Unicode).

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, i don't know about the connector, i use MySQLDB and it is working quite nicely. I work in UTF8 as well and i didn't have any problem.

Comment: answer questions in the answer field, write comments in the comment field